# Impossible to collab Visual Studio and VS for Mac?

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I use Mac, my friend uses Windows. We want to collaborate on a Unity project, had setup repo in Plastic SCM. He uses Visual Studio being extremely happy with the amount of features and convenience. We had an idea for me to try Visual Studio for Mac (I normally use VS Code). I thought: why not? When in Rome...

It turned out we can't collab like that? My understanding is:

- Visual Studio for Mac requires .csproj or .sln file to open a directory with a project
- These files are not supposed to be commited to a remote, shared repositry - .csproj contains local paths etc.
- Without those files in the repo I can't open the project in VS for Mac (!), let alone develop it
- I would expect the .csproj file or whatever **to contain all Unity files + others**, for example .editorconfig, which is important for synchronizing code formating between us.
- I can generate my own .csproj file in Unity, however it's ignoring .editorconfig
- I also don't want to start a new project via VS for Mac, which would create .sln and .csproj files. We already have a project on Plastic SCM

Therefore there is no option to share a repo that can be developed in his Windows + Visual Studio and mine Mac + VS for Mac envs.

Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: The csproj / sln files should be recreated by Unity the first time you open the project ... maybe you have to adjust this in your Unity preferences? If you open a script via double clicking on it within Unity what happens?

Comment: It opens in Visual Studio for Mac. So you're suggesting that each of us should have his own csproj / sln. That would work but I need non-Unity files (eg. .editorconfig) in Visual Studio, which according to my research is not supported

Comment: It should not be a problem to collab between Mac and Windows, although I would recommend you to use Rinder IDE instead of Visual Studio but that's up to you.
Also you can try and use ".gitignore" file and specify the types of files you want to ignore, which means you will have the files but it will be ignored inside your repository. You can read more about it here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: `.csproj` / `.sln` are anyway recompiled by Unity so you shouldn't share those but use your local ones yes. `.editorconfig` doesn't see to be related to those so this is another story and you have full control over what you share and what not via your `.gitignore` configurations (have not much experience with Plastic SCM tbh so no clue how it is done there but I would expect .gitignore to work the same since they claim to have seamless compatibility with git)

Comment: I see what you guys suggest. But then again, the problem comes down to the fact that Unity can't generate csproj file that fully satisfies my needs. This has nothing to do with git/plastic. The root cause of that is Visual Studio for Mac is apparently just a hollow, impotent tool (not complaining, I obviously know who is in charge of C# and VS and what is their attitude to Apple :P ). Got to try Rider, I used to love JetBrains tools.